# Ansbile OCI collection- Inventory Plugin

Tags: ansible-inventory, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Greats from Brazil !!

I 'm using ansible 2.10 and OCI collection installed from ansible-galaxy.

When I run

```
ansible-inventory -i inventory.oci.yml --list -vvvvvvvv
```

I get this error

```
* Failed to parse inventory.oci.yml with ansible_collections.oracle.oci.plugins.inventory.oci plugin: local variable 'tenancy' referenced before assignment
```

I got  it isn't a configuration error, because, when I run the OCI-Cli command using the same config file its works.

this is my inventory file:

```
# demo.oci.yml
plugin:   oracle.oci.oci
 
# Optional fields to specify oci connection config:
config_file: ~/.oci/config
config_profile: default
auth_type: instance_principal
tenancy : ocid1.tenancy.oc1.xxxxxxxxx
```

I have tried both with and without tenancy  value,  in  both in config file and in inventory file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the field option `instance_principal_authentication` instead of option `auth_type` in the inventory (.oci.yml) file. And the field `tenancy` is not a valid input option for the inventory file, the value for that is picked up from the config file. Please have a look at this [link for valid options for oci inventory.](https://github.com/oracle/oci-ansible-collection/blob/master/plugins/inventory/oci.py)

So your inventory file should look like:

```
# demo.oci.yml
plugin:   oracle.oci.oci
 
# Optional fields to specify oci connection config:
config_file: ~/.oci/config
config_profile: DEFAULT
instance_principal_authentication: true
```